# dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: -> references a package I am not using

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, bcrypt

meteor.js noob here.  I am trying to run an application I just cloned from github... I am getting the following error about `lazy symbol binding`

```
W20160817-10:30:52.177(-4)? (STDERR) dyld: Symbol not found: _node_module_register
W20160817-10:30:52.177(-4)? (STDERR)   Referenced from: /Users/user1/.meteor/packages/npm-bcrypt/.0.8.7.cg8y4v++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/bcrypt/build/Release/bcrypt_lib.node
W20160817-10:30:52.177(-4)? (STDERR)   Expected in: dynamic lookup
W20160817-10:30:52.177(-4)? (STDERR)
```

The app does not use bcrypt to the best of my knowledge, as it only uses OAuth. I have also looked through the packages list, and bcrypt is not there (as it shouldn't be)  I have tried to resolve the issue through...

```
sudo rm -rf node_modules
npm install
npm rebuild <package>
```

as suggested in some topics with similar issues.

I have also done

```
meteor add <package>
meteor remove <package>
```

I have tried to install bcrypt to see if the app will run, I have looked through a whole bunch of similar error messages on stackoverflow.  Nothing seems to help.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like there's a version conflict between your host npm and the meteor bundled npm. What happens if you blow away `node_modules` and then `meteor npm install`?

Comment: I have tried that a few times.  I still get the same error.  All of the questions I read that had similar issues made your suggestion as the fix.  However, it doesn't seem to work for me! extremely frustrating...

Comment: What's the repo url? I'll try to reproduce. You might need to open an issue with the dev(s)...

Comment: I solved the problem using NVM. I don't quite know what I did, but it worked...somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a massive amount of attempts, I somehow solved the problem by installing nvm, uninstalling and reinstalling node, dropping the node_modules and reinstantiating them, and updating the bcrypt indirect dependency.

It seems that installing NVM is what made the biggest difference.

Comment: I got same problem. Can you tell final version of installed node, npm and meteor, please?